# WebView Inside SwipeRefreshLayout Scroll Issue

Tags: android, webview, swiperefreshlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I am trying to implement a **Webiew** inside SwipeRefreshLayout, but somehow the **SwipeRefreshLayout** is blocking my webview from scrolling upwards. I have searched the entire stackoverflow but could not find any working solution on Android 6.0

**NestedScrollView is not working

Any custom SwipeRefreshLayout or WebViews are not working**

here is my XML

Please help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: WebViews doesnt fits very well with Android components, you better implement the SwypeToRefresh inside the HTML that you show in the WebView.

Comment: Its a third party website so i can do that

Comment: If you dont find a solution, add a button in the ActionBar, or over the WebView itself